# How to Merge Two Arraylists with only Unique Items Powershell

Tags: powershell, arraylist

I need to have the ability to merge two arraylists in powershell, but only the unique items. Here's the logic of what I am trying to do:

1. Create a main arraylist.
2. Iterate through some other objects and each time it:
   a) Calls a Method which creates a separate arraylist with several items in it
   b) Adds the unique items from that separate arraylist into my main arraylist

I am wondering what the most efficient way to do this is? I'd really like to only add the unique elements in the first place, rather than add everything then remove the elements that are not unique.

Currently, I am using $arraylist.AddRange($temp_arraylist) to merge the two, and then $arraylist | select -uniq

But I've noticed that takes a relatively long time. I'd really like to only add the unique items in the first place.

Comment: take a look at the `hashset` dotnet type. it can do set operations that seem fairly fast. this article covers the basic ideas [and  includes linq stuff that is even faster ... 5 ways to select Unique items in PowerShell | RidiCurious.com — https://ridicurious.com/2018/04/13/unique-items-in-powershell/

Comment: hashset looks like the best option, thanks! Didn't even know that existed. The linq stuff seems interesting, but very complicated.

Comment: i have had fun with the hashset stuff ... and become utterly confused by the linq stuff. good luck with your project! [*grin*]